# Python - Dataclass: load attribute value from a dictionary containing an invalid name

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, casting, python-dataclasses

Unfortunately I have to load a dictionary containing an invalid name (which I can't change):

```
dict = {..., "invalid-name": 0, ...}
```

I would like to cast this dictionary into a `dataclass` object, but I can't define an attribute with this name.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Dict:
    ...
    invalid-name: int  # can't do this
    ...
```

The only solution I could find is to change the dictionary key into a valid one right before casting it into a `dataclass` object:

```
dict["valid_name"] = dict.pop("invalid-name")
```

But I would like to avoid using string literals...

Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: Why do you want to "avoid using string literals"? If there's one specific name you need to change, using a string literal is absolutely fine.

Comment: If you had *multiple* invalid names where you could simply replace `-` with `_`, you could setup up a loop, something like `for k in d: d[k] = k.replace('-', '_')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be using [dict-to-dataclass](https://pypi.org/project/dict-to-dataclass/). As mentioned in its documents it has two options:

1.passing dictionary keys

> It's probably quite common that your dataclass fields have the same names as the dictionary keys they map to but in case they don't, you can pass the dictionary key as the first argument (or the dict_key keyword argument) to field_from_dict:

```
@dataclass
class MyDataclass(DataclassFromDict):
    name_in_dataclass: str = field_from_dict("nameInDictionary")

origin_dict = {
    "nameInDictionary": "field value"
}

dataclass_instance = MyDataclass.from_dict(origin_dict)

>>> dataclass_instance.name_in_dataclass
"field value"
```

2. Custom converters

> If you need to convert a dictionary value that isn't covered by the defaults, you can pass in a converter function using field_from_dict's converter parameter:

```
def yes_no_to_bool(yes_no: str) -> bool:
    return yes_no == "yes"


@dataclass
class MyDataclass(DataclassFromDict):
    is_yes: bool = field_from_dict(converter=yes_no_to_bool)

dataclass_instance = MyDataclass.from_dict({"is_yes": "yes"})

>>> dataclass_instance.is_yes
True
```

Comment: It is nice to know that this library exists, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following code allow to filter the nonexistent keys :

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class ClassDict:
    valid-name0: str
    valid-name1: int  
    ...

dict = {..., "invalid-name": 0, ...}

dict = {k:v for k,v in dict.items() if k in tuple(e.name for e in dataclasses.fields(ClassDict).keys())}
```

However, I'm sure there should be a better way to do it since this is a bit hacky.

Comment: the `__dataclass_fields__` attribute is undocumented in dataclasses module, and shouldn't generally be used in user code. I would suggest using `dataclasses.fields` instead.

Comment: That's true, I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I would define a `from_dict` class method anyway, which would be a natural place to make the change.

```
@dataclass
class MyDict:

    ...
    valid_name: int
    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        d['valid_name'] = d.pop('invalid-name')
        return cls(**d)


md = MyDict.from_dict({'invalid-name': 3, ...})
```

Whether you should modify `d` in place or do something to avoid unnecessary copies is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library, which is likewise a de/serialization library built on top of dataclasses. It should similarly support [custom key mappings](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/custom_key_mappings.html), as needed in this case.

I've also timed it with the builtin `timeit` module, and found it to be (on average) about **5x** faster than a solution with `dict_to_dataclass`. I've added the code I used for comparison below.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from timeit import timeit
from typing_extensions import Annotated  # Note: in Python 3.9+, can import this from `typing` instead

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard, json_key
from dict_to_dataclass import DataclassFromDict, field_from_dict


@dataclass
class ClassDictWiz(JSONWizard):
    valid_name: Annotated[int, json_key('invalid-name')]


@dataclass
class ClassDict(DataclassFromDict):
    valid_name: int = field_from_dict('invalid-name')


my_dict = {"invalid-name": 0}

n = 100_000

print('dict-to-dataclass:  ', round(timeit('ClassDict.from_dict(my_dict)', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print('dataclass-wizard:   ', round(timeit('ClassDictWiz.from_dict(my_dict)', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))

i1, i2 = ClassDict.from_dict(my_dict), ClassDictWiz.from_dict(my_dict)
# assert we get the same result with both approaches
assert i1.__dict__ == i2.__dict__
```

Results, on my Mac OS X laptop:

```
dict-to-dataclass:   0.594
dataclass-wizard:    0.098
```